# Is it possible to post a file by JS without a form?

Tags: javascript, forms, upload, image

I've designed a webpage that posts some information like this

```
<form>
    <table>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input  name="a">
            </li>
            <li>
                <input  name="b">
            </li>
            <li>
                <input  name="c">
            </li>
        <ul>
    </table>
</form>
```

Now I want to upload a sequence of pictures in each `li`, and for some reason, I want each `li` to have a separate upload and after the uploaded succeeded the image can be  previewed in each `li`.
But because I have an "outter" `form`, I cannot create nested forms for each `li`. Therefore I want to post the pictures without forms with JavaScript, is it possible? Or is there any better solution to upload a sequences of pictures?

Comment: Try to resolve your conflicts

Comment: I tried to correct your question a bit and hope I didn't change any meaning. The table seems to be pretty useless and makes your HTML invalid. The question is, how do you want to upload the pictures? All at once when the user clicks a button? With the new HTML5 file API you don't have to wait until the upload finishes to show the picture, you can display it immediately afaik.

Comment: i mean if there are `<form><form></form></form>` like forms,some forms will be disappear,idont' know if you are meaning to put all things in a big form?

Comment: i want to upload the picture all at once when user chose a file. after that i want to post the file to the server and preview in the li label.

Comment: Why can't you try get method? ie appending the information to the destination url and send it?

Comment: Maybe this helps you a bit: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/file I understand your general idea but not your particular problem (i.e. what you want to do *exactly*).

Comment: How are they supposed to get the data in the first place? What happens when they hit the URI length imposed by some browsers when they try to encode large binary files in the URI?

Comment: ....ok,i just want to find a better solution or general solution to upload file to the server,because i dont' have other skills ,i want to   post each image use js ,and i found after i've write a form in it,it will disappear and have conflict with the outer.so i want to find a way to post the image without form ,so i can upload it to the server and preview it.  but my purpose is simple,so if there are some other beautiful ways to upload sequences ,it will be help ethier

Comment: You can't use two nested <form> tags. May I suggest you start with a simple tutorial like this? http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php

It should help giving you a general idea how this stuff works.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, one of this components can help to solve it:

jQuery Multiple File Upload Plugin: http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/

Multiple File Upload Magic: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Multiple_File_Upload_Magic

Ajax Upload: http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

Namastê !